# volar error: Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, volar

I update my extersion Vue Language Features (Volar) to v1.4.1
(with vue3 and ts)
then my code shows following error

[image]

radioButton is one of my table column
[image]

row and index are the data and index that I set into the table from API
should I cahange any setting or I need to fix my code?

Comment: It seems like you have not yet added the row props onto the `#radioButton` component.

Comment: @JishanShaikh 
radioButton is one of my table column

Comment: You probably didn't define row as props in your component, a type definition e.g., can be ```export default {
  props: {
    row: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```, which accepts row as a String type. Can you make sure you have definitions of both row and index? Where are you getting these values from (of row and index)?

Comment: row and index  are the data and the key from my table(i do set a list to my table), before i update my extension, the error didn't show

Comment: @JishanShaikh so i think it's not about props

Comment: The error clearly indicates that `row` is not defined or is out of scope. Underline on index indicates the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to fix this error:
first
`#radioButton="{ row, index }: any"`

second
update volar to next version...